# Remove string quotes from a array javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove `" "` from an array inside a string.

```
var test = "['a']"
var test1 = "['a','b']"
```

Expected Output:

```
var test_arr  = ['a']
var test1_arr = ['a','b']
```

I tried replacing, didn't work

```
var test_arr = test.replace(/\"/, '');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways to accomplish that.

1. `JSON.parse('["a","b"]')` note that the values need to be in double-quotes.
2. `"['a','b']".replace(/[['\]]/g, '').split(',')` note that you need to split after replacing the unwanted chars

Both yield an array containing the original strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert the single quotes inside the strings to double quotes first to convert the string to a valid JSON, and then we can use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to get the required array like:

```js
var test = "['a']"
var test1 = "['a','b']"

var parseStr = str => JSON.parse(str.replace(/'/g, '"'))
var test_arr  = parseStr(test)
var test1_arr = parseStr(test1)

console.log(test_arr)
console.log(test1_arr)
```